# method onItemClickListener error for open webview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

- *First*, i have error in `lv.setOnItemClickLister`:

  ```
  Multiple markers at this line
      - The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type 
       AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})
      - OnItemSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type
      - The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the 
       type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new 
       OnItemSelectedListener(){})
  ```
- *Second* : i have error in `page = mylist.get(position);`:

> page cannot be resolved to a variable

**My code:**

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;


        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.content.Intent;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.ListAdapter;
        import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


        public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment  {

            public FindPeopleFragment(){}
              protected ListView lv;
              protected ListAdapter adapter;
              SimpleAdapter Adapter;
              HashMap<String, String> map;
              ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
              String[] Pil;
              String[] Ltn;
              String[] Gbr;


              public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pulau, container,false);

                    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);

                    Pil = new String[] {"Pulau Gusung", "Binatang Laut Khas"};
                    Ltn = new String[] {"Baca Selengkapnya...", "Baca Selengkapnya..."};
                    Gbr = new String[] {Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_photos),
                                        Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_photos),

                                                 };

                    mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Pil.length; i++){
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("list", Pil[i]);
                        map.put("latin", Ltn[i]);
                        map.put("gbr", Gbr[i]);
                        mylist.add(map);             
                    }

                    Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, R.layout.item_kepulauan,
                              new String[] {"list", "latin", "gbr"}, new int[] {R.id.tv_nama, R.id.tv_des, R.id.imV});
                    lv.setAdapter(Adapter);

                    return rootView;

                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() { //error
                         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                             page = mylist.get(position); //error
                             String url = "file:///android_asset/tampilhome.html";
                             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                             i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                             startActivity(i);
                         } });
                  }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either supply an `OnItemClickListener` to `setOnItemClickListener()`, or supply an `OnItemSelectedListener` to `setOnItemSelectedListener()`.

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to achieve, so no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from the function so the line of code will never run. Move return statement to after the ClickListener.